# Java Parameterized Type from Class object

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I have a class called Foo with a generic type.

```
public class Foo<T> { ...
```

And I have another, non parameterized class called Foo Factory that generates Foos.

```
public class FooFactory {
    public static Foo createFoo() { 
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to pass a `Class clazz` parameter into `createFoo` so that I can create a `Foo<clazz>`?

```
public class FooFactory {
    public static Foo createFoo(Class clazz) {
        return new Foo<clazz>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the `createFoo` factory method generic:

```
public static <T> Foo<T> createFoo(Class<T> clazz) {
    return new Foo<T>();
}
```

Well as it turns out, you don't even need `clazz`; Java will infer `<T>` for you, so this will suffice:

```
public static <T> Foo<T> createFoo() {
    return new Foo<T>();
}
```

Comment: I imagine you could do without the `Class<T> clazz` parameter with this solution, could you not?

Comment: Do you even need to provide a `Class<T>` as a parameter? I always forget exactly how smart the inference is. I would think `Foo<A> a = createFoo();` should work.

Comment: Or just `FooFactory.<A> createFoo()`

Comment: Very true, `clazz` isn't needed.

Comment: @TomG Or `Foo<Integer> iFoo = FooFactory.createFoo();` where the compiler will infer `Integer` for `T`.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without making `createFoo` generic?

Comment: You could have a non-generic `createFoo` method, but to use it, you'd force the return type to be a raw `Foo`, or else you have to cast the return object to a generic type, for example `(Foo<Integer>)`, with the accompanying unchecked cast warning.  The generic factory method is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the `createFoo` function generic:

```
public static <T> Foo<T> createFoo() {
    return new Foo<>();
}
```

returns an instance of type `Foo<T>` and does so for any type `T`. This is indicated by writing `<T>` at the beginning of the method signature, which declares `T` as a new type variable, specifying that `createFoo()` is a generic method.

Check out : [Generic Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)